# Clonezilla Freezes on PXE boot image restore

Tags: centos, clonezilla, drbl

I'm just wondering if anybody hads ever hit this problem.

I'm usng DRBL Clonezilla on Centos 6.  When I go to image the lab it boots the os from the server via PXE boot and everything seems to be working fine, but then it will freeze at 0% complete when attempting to deploy the image.

I've tested this on a single machine with the number of clients to wait for being 1 and also with the time to wait being 2 minutes, and it will sit there for hours at 0%

I've never hit a problem before where the server is able to communicate with the machine and boot the OS, but still have a problem deploying the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the problem was that the switch that was being used was reconfigured since the previous image and the broadcast address was blocked.